# I want to convert to Islam but I don't know what is the correct shahada?

Tags: fiqh, conversion, shahada

I've seen on youtube videos of shahada but some shahada are

> Ashhadu an laa ilaaha illa-llah wa ashhadu anna muhammadan rasulullah
> أَشْهَدُ أَنْ لاَ إِلَهَ إِلاَّ اللَّهُ وَأَشْهَدُ أَنَّ مُحَمَّدًا رَسُولُ اللَّهِ

and some other shahada are

> Ashhadu an laa ilaaha illa-llah was ashhadu anna muhammadan abduhu wa rasuluhu
> أَشْهَدُ أَنْ لاَ إِلَهَ إِلاَّ اللَّهُ، وَأَشْهَدُ أَنَّ مُحَمَّدًا عَبْدُهُ وَرَسُولُهُ

I don't know which one is the right one ?

Comment: They are both correct and both have occurred in ahadith. You can say both of them one after the other, and also realize that one is inclusive of the meaning of the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct. Understanding the meaning is important because faith is belief in the heart and expression upon the tongue and action upon the limbs.

First one: I testify that there is no God but Allah. And I testify that Muhammed(ﷺ) is the messenger of Allah.

Second one: I testify that there is no God but Allah. And I testify that Muhammed(ﷺ) is his(Allah) slave and his(Allah) messenger.

> Umar ibn al-Khattab reported: We were sitting with the Messenger of
> Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, one day when a man appeared
> with very white clothes and very black hair. There were no signs of
> travel on him and we did not recognize him. He sat down in front of
> the Prophet and rested his knees by his knees and placed his hands on
> his thighs. The man said, “O Muhammad, tell me about Islam.” The
> Prophet said, “Islam is to **testify there is no God but Allah and
> Muhammad is the Messenger of Allah**, to establish prayer, to give
> charity, to fast the month of Ramadan, and to perform pilgrimage to
> the House if a way is possible.” The man said, “You have spoken
> truthfully.” We were surprised that he asked him and said he was
> truthful. He said, “Tell me about faith.” The Prophet said, “Faith is
> to believe in Allah, His angels, his Books, His Messengers, the Last
> Day, and to believe in providence, its good and its evil.” The man
> said, “You have spoken truthfully. Tell me about excellence.” The
> Prophet said, “Excellence is to worship Allah as if you see Him, for
> if you do not see Him, He surely sees you.” The man said, “Tell me
> about the final hour.” The Prophet said, “The one asked does not know
> more than the one asking.” The man said, “Tell me about its signs.”
> The Prophet said, “The slave girl will give birth to her mistress and
> you will see barefoot, naked, and dependent shepherds compete in the
> construction of tall buildings.” Then, the man returned and I
> remained. The Prophet said to me, “O Umar, do you know who he was?” I
> said, “Allah and his messenger know best.” The Prophet said, “Verily,
> he was Gabriel who came to teach you your religion.” Source: Ṣaḥīḥ
> Muslim 8

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you mean with `First one is correct`? The second is incorrect or wrong or what?

Comment: So both are correct ?

Comment: Both are fine. But first one is preferable. First one is (Ash hadu an laa ilaha illallah wa ash hadu anna muhammadan rasulullah)

Comment: @Riyaz, `first one is preferable.` Could you please prove why? To my knowledge, Allah Himself called the Prophet (SAW) `Abdullah` in 72:19, which means `slave of Allah`. This is what Allah is preferring him to be - a slave of His. Your statement is against Allah's will.

Comment: @Muslim Please check Hadith of Jibreel who came to teach the religion. The first pillar of Islam words are "To testify there is no God but Allah and Muhammad is the Messenger of Allah"

Comment: Still, the Hadith is in contradiction with Qur'an.

Comment: The second wording has also occurred in several ahadith such as on the conversion of [Abu Dhar](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3522), the conversion of [Thumama](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1764a), and the conversion of the [mother of Abu Hurairah](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2491) , the variant [hadith on the pillars of Islam](https://sunnah.com/muslim:16c) and the variant [hadith on jihad](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2608) , the variant wording of [the Hadith of Jibreel](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2610) etc.

Comment: @Muslim It is not in contradiction to the Quran, omitting the attribute 'slave of Allah' does not mean that one denies it. There are hundreds of attributes of both Allah and the Prophet which are mentioned in the Quran but are not explicitly mentioned in the shahada. The phrase محمد رسول الله is found as such in the  [Quran 48:29](https://quran.com/48/29?translations=20).

Comment: @UmH so both are equally good and valid?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Both are valid.

Comment: @Muslim No it's not in contradiction with Qur'an, please don't try to decide yourself what Hadith does and doesn't contradict the Qur'an. This job is entirely done by qualified Hadith scholars.